# How to arrange source files in Ocsigen project

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocsigen

I have created a simple Ocsigen project from basic template. Everything was fine until I decided I'd like to put all my source files in `src` directory and create more subdirectiories inside it too, so that my source code is partitioned into modules and arranged nicely.

Unfortunately when I try to compile the project, only the files in the main directory get compiled and the `src` directory is not searched for source files. I have read the makefiles generated by the project template and tried to figure out a way to make it work, but with no success. Specifically it's not sufficient just to change values of `CLIENT_FILES` and `SERVER_FILES` in `Makefile.options`. I tried to impose recursive search like so:

```
SERVER_FILES := $(shell find src -name "*.eliom" -or -name "*.eliomi")
```

but it didn't work. `Makefile` apparently requires much more changes to accept that. I also tried with flat structure using `$(wildcard src/*.eliom)`, but that didn't work either.

So is there any way to achieve what I need without making changes to half the template `Makefile`, which is quite magical for me, difficult to modify, and even more difficult to completely comprehend and rewrite.

Comment: In https://github.com/ocsigen/ocsigen-start/issues/365 , the ocsigen devs seem to say they'd rather have people develop external libraries and keep the website code as small as possible.

Comment: Well, perhaps. But still my whole team including myself prefers to separate source code from various configs, readmes and makefiles. Besides a website code could and should be small indeed. But not that small as to fit in a single file. Especially if you consider all the HTML that needs to be generated. I see no point in making that a separate library.

Comment: Maybe you can create a directory just for building with symbolic links to the actual files.

Comment: Then I pollute the main directory with symbolic links to files instead of files themselves, which seems even worse to me.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this ? I'm going nuts compiling my files by hand, there has to be a way to get a Makefile working with a clean src/ directory at the very least

Comment: Unfortunately, not. What I have done in the end was to start rewriting the Makefile from scratch, adding new features as I needed them. One thing I could never do right was to automatically figure out dependencies between source files. There is a tool in the OCaml compiler to do that, but it goes nuts when a cyclic dependency occurs. This happens quite often accidentally and should be treated as an error, but unfortuantely is not. Instead the project compiles well and produces a binary that crashes on startup. Also I have never implemented compilation to native machine code.

Answer (score 1):

I can refer you to this very helpful post from Danny Willems [Ocsigen: how to compile an Eliom project. Understand the compilation process in deep.](https://blog.danny-willems.be/ocsigen-compile-eliom-projet-understand-compilation-process-deep/)
If you want, you can make it automated with any framework for example if you want to use ocamlbuild you can create a Makefile yourself and put in it these lines

```
SOURCE_FILES = src
OCB_FLAGS = -plugin-tags "package(eliom.ocamlbuild)" -use-ocamlfind -I $(SOURCE_FILES)
OCB = ocamlbuild $(OCB_FLAGS)
...
$(PATH_YOU_WANT)$(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME).js:
  $(OCB) -no-hygiene $@
```

and then in a `_tags` file write:

```
true: eliom_ppx
<*/server/*>: package(eliom.server), thread
<*/client/*>: package(eliom.client)
```

First line is needed if you used ppx extension of eliom in your code that is sometimes necessary. Issuing make in a shell, ocamlbuild will compile your code into `_build/src/server` and `_build/src/client`